# jquery replace div content html()

Tags: jquery

I'm just try to replace the content of a div with new content binded to a click event.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pCckh/)

When I use `appendTo()` instead of of `html()` it's working, but I need to clear the old content out so I'm a bit confused why this is not working like it should do

Comment: You should put some code to support your question along with jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using `content` in place of `selector` and `selector` in place of `content`, you need to use `#` with id selctor. you can do it this way

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/pCckh/1/)**

```
function showitnow() {
    var div_data = "<div ><a href='XXX'>XXX</a></div>";
    $("#test1").html(div_data);

}

$("#button1").click(function() {
     showitnow();
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your fiddle, That should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pCckh/3/

```
function showitnow() {
    var div_data = "<div ><a href='XXX'>XXX</a></div>";
    $("#test1").html(div_data);
   //  ^---selector----^----------your content
}

$("#button1").click(function() {
    showitnow();
 // ^----------------remove the var and just call the function when click the button
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try this..
playing your JQuery as parent and child..

```
<div id="Destination"> 
    <div class="child_content"> item 1 </div>
    <div class="child_content"> item 2 </div>
</div>

    <div id="Source"> 
    <div class="child_content"> item 1 </div>
    <div class="child_content"> item 2 </div>
</div>

      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Source .child_content").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
                $(this).appendTo("#Destination");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Hope this helpfull..

Answer (score -1):

[Please have a look!](http://jsfiddle.net/Shreejeetd/pCckh/194/) Expected result...

Only few modification required in same example.

```
<div id = 'div_data'>
<button id="button1">BUTTON1</button>
div>

<div id="test2"></div>
```